# telegram importContacts method not working

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Could you please  let me know why some of the telegram methods are not working?
for example "https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/sendMessage" works fine and it never returns 404 error whereas [https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/importContacts](https://api.telegram.org/bot%7Btoken%7D/importContacts) and many others are not working at all.

You can find the list of all methods here and you can try them
https://core.telegram.org/methods

Thanks  for responding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Telegram platform offers two separate APIs.

- **Telegram Bot API** which is documented at [Telegram bot docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) and relies on the HTTPS protocol. `api.telegram.org` is the entry point for this API.
- **Telegram Client API** which is documented at [Telegram core documentation](https://core.telegram.org/api) and relies on the MTProto protocol.

The Telegram bot protocol is significantly more limited than the Telegram Core API, if you're looking to create a client to use your own account, you need to use the MTProto API.

Comment: Thank you very much